# WPF button focus style being overriden when placed in content presenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

## The Setup

I have the following style that I apply to most of the windows in my application:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyNamespace.ChromeWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="CustomChromeTest" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridMain" Background="{StaticResource MainFormColor}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I use it to customize the window chrome around my window (I have removed that part) so all the actual contents of the window go inside the content presenter.  I use this style like so:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
    Style="{DynamicResource CustomChromeTest}">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFControlLibrary;component/Resources/ChromeWindow.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Margin="5" Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
    <Button Margin="5" Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
    <Button Margin="5" Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
    <Button Margin="5"  Content="Button"  Width="75"/>

</StackPanel>
```

This XAML above produces a window that looks like this:

[image: Test window]

## The Problem

In a normal window, when the user is tabbing through the controls, **the current button is highlighted to show the user the current button**.  Note the border around the 3rd button below.

[image]

For some reason, **the moment I use my style, this feature disappears** and there is no indication of which button has focus, even though the user can tab like normal.  Why is this and how can I restore **the built-in** functionality.

## Please Note

I use this style with dozens of windows and hundreds of controls. I do not want to use a style on every control with a trigger that displays a border when the control has focus.  I want to restore the default functionality that was being used before I applied my custom window style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to define the `ContentPresenter` as `AdornerDecorator` for `Window` and it will work as intended. Which I didn't figure out at first either apparently :)

Style;

```
<Style x:Key="CustomChromeTest" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Grid x:Name="GridMain" Background="Yellow">
              <AdornerDecorator>                    
                <ContentPresenter/>
              </AdornerDecorator>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

and your window...

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2" x:Name="Testeroo" 
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{StaticResource CustomChromeTest}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="750">

       <StackPanel>
           <Button Margin="5" Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
           <Button Margin="5" Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
           <Button Margin="5" Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
           <Button Margin="5"  Content="Button"  Width="75"/>
       </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.