# Screen Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF app with a header that consists of a progress bar, date and time, and status. This app also contains a Footer with 5 buttons to navigate between different screens (settings, results, products, etc.). I did this originally by making the navigation button bar a usercontrol and all other content is in seperate windows. I am not entirely happy with this and am sure there is a better way. Is it better to have a main screen with only the header and footer and do all other content as seperate user controls? Or should all windows stay seperate and show the user controls for header and footer on initialize. I currently have the latter but it requires me to track what windows are open to keep from opening more than one of the same. I also think it may be more manageable to have the main entry point and window settings and just aadd content to center section. Any advice on best way to achieve this is appreciated.[image: Depiction of layout]

Comment: You could just create a window template like this fella did in a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834926/wpf-button-focus-style-being-overriden-when-placed-in-content-presenter/44836497#44836497)

Comment: What I like to do in this scenario is to Have the Main window contain all the Globally available items (header, footer, menu, etc). And then use `Page` Controls for your content in the center, rather than `Window`

Comment: The other reason i like using a `Frame` with a `Page` as the Source, is you dont need to track windows and can have simple logic for navigation.

Comment: @Ginger Ninja I have never used the Frame/Page. If I set the Source property of frame to binding, what is the assignment to frame.source to get page to show?

Comment: got it to work with:    frmContent.NavigationService.Navigate(new Products()); Thanks @Ginger Ninja

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain my experience with your problem and how I solved it.

What I can suggest is to create custom controls for footer and header.

Then create a page control that inherits from Page named CustomPage for example, and put footer and header layouts inside CustomPage layout.

Then create another and last control inheriting from CustomPage named for example CustomPageContent. This page will present footer and header and you will customize it with specific content for every different page. You will have at this point all functionalities from Page Control and all logic for navigation will be supplied. You will be able to controll this contents as a frame.

I think that this solution will give you a little bit work but is a really elegant solution and your code will be simplyfied.

Hope will help!